# Prompt user for file input

Tags: python, input

I have code that manipulates data of a file that I currently have hard-coded in the script.  I want to be able to prompt the user to chose the input file rather than having to hard-code it.  Here is what I have for input.  Instead of always using myfile.txt, I'd like the user to be able to choose the file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rU') as input_file:
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` (Python 2) or `input` (Python 3) to read the file name and then use that in `open`

Comment: Choose it how? Through a file picker (see Tkinter)? The command line (consider `sys.argv`)?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `input` function on Python 3, or `raw_input` if you're using Python 2:

```
# Python 3
with open(input(), 'rU') as input_file:

# Python 2
with open(raw_input(), 'rU') as input_file:
```

This prompts the user for text input and returns it as a string. In your case, this will prompt for a file path to be input.

If you add an argument to this function, it prints something without a newline before input is requested, for example:

```
input("File: ")
```

Here's an example program which uses the `input` function:

```
answer = input()
print("Your answer was: " + answer)
```

When run:

```
foo
Your answer was: foo
```

Comment: Might also want to add a prompt for the `input` and `raw_input` functions

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks.